# Get status of a dynamically generated mat-checkbox when clicking on the label

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-ngmodel

im trying to pass a dynamically generated checkbox state to a method that is called when you click the label

this is the html:

```
<div *ngFor="let label of consent.labels" style="flex-direction: column">
  <div [ngClass]="{'accept': consent.aceptado === true, 'optional': !consent.obligatorio }">
    <section style="margin-top: 5px;">

      <mat-checkbox color="primary" [(ngModel)]="consent.aceptado" (change)="verify()">
        <div [innerHTML]="label.label | safeHtml" (click)="detailSubConsent(checkBoxState, $event)"></div>
      </mat-checkbox>

    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

as additional information, with event.preventDefault() I prevent the state of the checkbox to change when I click on the label

Is there any way to capture the current state of the dynamically generated checkbox to pass it to the method that executes on click?

Comment: did you try to pass `consent.aceptado` instead of `checkBoxState`?

Comment: @hous consent.aceptado comes from database to indicate if the checkbox has to be checked or not by default. It would not be valid for the case in which the user changes the value of the checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always linking the same checkbox to the same ngModel, so if you have a list of them, you will end up with a lot of confusion (all of them will have the same value), you should link every separate checkbox to a different ngModel, I suggest creating a new object with keys for each label, now that I don't know your label object type definition, I will demo the solution assuming each label has a unique Id.

```
   <div *ngFor="let label of consent.labels" style="flex-direction: column">    
      <mat-checkbox color="primary" [(ngModel)]="obj[label.id]">
    <div [innerHTML]="label.label | safeHtml" (click)="detailSubConsent(label.id, $event)"></div>

      </mat-checkbox>
    </div>


   detailSubConsent(id, $event){
   //access the state as shown below 
   this.obj[id]
   }
```